# Can't find View in Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting the error

ViewDoesNotExist at /
Could not import blog.views. View does not exist in module blog.

With Django

My URLS file looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^Blog/', include('Blog.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and my directory tree looks like this

```
Blog
_manage.py
_Blog
__wsgi.py
__urls.py
__settings.py
__ __init__.py
_blog
__views.py
__tests.py
__Templates
____index.html
__models.py
__ __init__.py
```

And in the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from blog.models import posts

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

Further Debugging:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.2.3:1337/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  209.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  27.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  101.                     (lookup_view, mod_name))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: Could not import blog.views. View does not exist in module blog.
```

Comment: How did you do this 'futher debbuging' in django?

Answer (score 8):

Based on your debugging output it seems that the **blog** application isn't present in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you forgot include your 'blog' application into django installed applications on settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Check capitalization in your naming and also make sure you have an **init**.py in your app.